# What's the difference between "normal" and " none " values in CSS property content?

Tags: css, properties, pseudo-element

I am learning css and I don't understand the difference between those two values(normal and none) of "content" property.
Are those values the same ?? If so, why do I need both?

```
<style>
  .p01::before {
    content: none;
  }
  
  .p02::before {
    content: normal;
  }
</style
```

Comment: Just search on google.....[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've already read this page, but don't understand difference between those two values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-content-3/#content-property)

> normal
>
> For ::before and ::after, **this computes to none**.

Comment: Can you explain me this example, what is going on here՞   I update question....

Comment: @VopshmVopshmm it should be `#a` and not `a`

Comment: I try this code without "a" identifikator(<p> you </p>), but the result is same....

Comment: @VopshmVopshmm https://jsfiddle.net/q9wart0u/